# how to use graphicspath?

Tags: graphics, diagrams

I have a picture in my desktop, how can i use it by set graphicspath? I checked some examples, still no idea.
Below is an example, but it compile error

```
\graphicspath{{C:/}{Users/}{Me/}{Desktop/}}
\begin{figure}[tbh]
\centering
\includegraphics[]{f6f2a0b.jpg} %
\caption{blablaballla.}
\label{fig:SM}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Each directory *path* should be in its own set of braces. But what you seem to have done here is put each part of the path in its own set, which won't work.  Assuming you want to set one directory which is `C:/Users/Me/Desktop/` then your command should be `\graphicspath{{C:/Users/Me/Desktop/}}`.